How can I extrude faces in a desired angle that I need?
I want to make a simple but exact model of my room. And it turned out to not have any 90° corners in it.
That's why I want to find out how can I make my "corners" in any degrees I need.
For example how to make two walls that have 93° angle between them?
As you can tell I am pretty new to blender, all I did so far was low-poly figures but they don't need any exact angles so it's different.

Edit: As suggested by Gordon, select your face, select a vertex at the corner in order to make it active, switch the Transform Pivot Point to Active Element, and rotate the face 3° on Z:


I usually use Active Element as Transform Pivot Point for things like that, this way I don't have to bother with changing the 3D cursor for each new corner I want to rotate.

Oh yes you're right, it's smarter

You can rotate any object (for example, a Cube or an Empty) to the desired orientation.

Then you save the orientation of the object:

You can now use saved orientation while transforming mesh or extruding(just hit X, Y or Z while transforming or use Gizmo). And don't forget to change it back to Global or Local after you finished.

However, I'd prefer to decompose these walls into separate objects (planes or scaled cubes) rotated at the desired angle. It’s better to keep mesh orientation aligned with object orientation, as this allows for the use of symmetry modifiers, movement along local axes, etc. Additionally, accessing local transformations is much faster than setting up custom ones.

Not sure the 3D cursor part is necessary? I did the steps without it.

Thanks! Correct! It turns out you don’t have to snap 3D Cursor to the object, so you can skip the step.
